# Why network location provider returns null? Android

Tags: android, geolocation

In my app I am getting current location using Network provider. In this respect I have developed some code, you can see it below.

```
public class MyGPS extends Service implements LocationListener
{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private final Context mContext;

    public MyGPS (Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Check network status
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.e("Location ", "Network enabled");

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,1, this);
                if (locationManager != null) 
                {
                    Log.e("Location ", "Location manager is not null");
                    Location networkLocation= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (networkLocation != null) {
                        return networkLocation;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("Location ", "networkLocation object is null");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Location ", "Problum in getLocation()");
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

By running the above piece of code it shows debug message  `Log.e("Location ", "networkLocation object is null");`

Now my question is why the `networkLocation` object is null. Please help me in this respect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It returns 'null', when the Service is disabled in Settings > Location and Security > location through network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the permission?
manifest
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
manifest

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Yes dear I have declared the permission

Answer (score 0):

When the device get the location it will invoke the `onLocationChanged` listener. In the above case you are trying to get the `lastKnownLocation`. If there is no `lastKnownLocation` it will return as `null`.

So Please save the location from `onLocationChanged` listener.

Answer (score 0):

> public Location getLastKnownLocation (String provider) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned. Parameters
>   provider  the name of the provider Returns
>
> ```
> the last known location for the provider, or null
> ```